# dropdown-select is not showing the right value using bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, bootstrap-select

I have some kind of trouble, actually my code should be working just fine, but there is some bug here...

eventhough I already set the value of my dropdown select, it's appearance still not changed, in my case here, the value of second dropdown-select showing the first option eventhough I set it to be the second option.. why is this happening? My first dropdown select show the value just fine though...

I use bootstrap-select 1.13.15 in my codeigniter and my browser is google chrome

here is my view

```
<!-- modal edit -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="MoEditCP" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      <center><h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Catatan</h3></center>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="<?php echo site_url('server/updatePI');?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-form-label">Nama Pelanggar :</label><br>
            <select id="anggota1" class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
                    <?php foreach ($daftaranggota as $dafang) { ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $dafang['nim'] ?>"><?php echo $dafang['namaLengkap'] ?> - <?php echo $dafang['nim'] ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-form-label">Tanggal Pelanggaran :</label><br>
            <input type="date" name="tgl1" class="form-control" id="tgl1">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-form-label">Sanksi Kedisiplinan :</label><br>
            <select id="sd1" class="selectpicker">
              <option value="Ringan">Ringan</option>
              <option value="Sedang">Sedang</option>
              <option value="Berat">Berat</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-form-label">Catatan Pelanggaran :</label>
            <input type="text" name="cp1" class="form-control" id="cp1">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="hidden" name="nimPenulis1" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('nim') ?>" class="form-control" id="nimPenulis1">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn_update">Buat</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal edit -->
```

here is my script:

```
<script>
...
 $('#tabelCP tbody').on('click', 'button.edit_cp', function() {
                let tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                let row = tabel_cp.row(tr);
                let data = row.data();

                $('#MoEditCP').modal('show');
                $('#anggota1').val(data.nimPelanggar);
                $('#tgl1').val(data.tgltrue);
                $('#sd1').val(data.tingkat);
                $('#nimPenulis1').val("<?php echo $this->session->userdata('nim') ?>");
              });
...
</script>
```

Comment: can you print to console the script's data?

Comment: do you mean console in inspect ctrl+shift+i? there is no error report there

Comment: i mean console.log(data.tingkat), is it the right data?

Comment: yes it is, my option-select is working fine when I delete ```class="selectpicker"```, but when I use it, the option-select won't show the right value

Comment: sorry @AbhishekMalik, I guess what I am doing wrong here is, I am using select-bootstrap, and so, to change the value I need to code it like it was supposed to be, here is the example 
```$('#sel_users').select();```
```var value = somevalue;```
```$('#sel_users').val(value);```
```$('#sel_users').select().trigger('change');```
, I got the answer from here https://makitweb.com/change-selected-option-in-select2-dropdown-with-jquery/, thanks for answering